# How to reshape dates and sum a column in R xts

Tags: r, reshape, xts

Maybe this question is very simple, but i couldn't find a way to reshape an irregular xts variable to hour base and sum the values of another column.
My xts variable looks like this:

```
2016-03-06 00:00:10    1
2016-03-06 00:00:39    1
2016-03-06 00:00:44    1
2016-03-06 00:00:57    1
2016-03-06 00:00:58    1
2016-03-06 00:01:56    1
```

But I need something like this:

```
[,1]
2016-03-06 00:00:00    5
2016-03-06 00:01:00    6
...
```

It is pretty much what we can easily do with reshape on pandas:

```
series.resample(self.freq, how='sum', label='right')
```

thanks

Comment: Can [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019187/why-is-there-no-apply-hourly-in-r-with-xts-zoo) be helpful ? Especially check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019187/why-is-there-no-apply-hourly-in-r-with-xts-zoo#comment22849715_16019730) comment.

Comment: Yes @RonakShah, it is, the only problem with this approach is that I got irregular datetimes, even using the second example it is still show irregular datetimes instead of something like hour 1:00:00, 2:00:00, etc

Comment: hey @RonakShah I changed the align.time.down custom function a little bit and got the results in regular datetimes, tks

Comment: That is great to know. :)

Answer (score 0):

`period.apply()` should do it:

```
ep <- endpoints(df.xts, 'minutes') 
period.apply(df.xts, ep ,sum)
```