# How to use apply.daily/period.apply for calculating maximum per column in XTS time series?

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have a problem using the `period.apply` function for my case of a high resolution time series analysis.

I want to calculate statistics(Mean for different Periods, Stddev etc.) for my data which is in 10 min intervals. To calculate hourly means worked fine like described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16019730/9735690).

It creates a new xts object with means calculated for each column.  How do I calculate maximum values for each column?

This reproducible example describes the structure of my data:

```
library(xts)
start <- as.POSIXct("2018-05-18 00:00")
tseq <- seq(from = start, length.out = 1440, by = "10 mins")
Measurings <- data.frame(
  Time = tseq,
  Temp = sample(10:37,1440, replace = TRUE, set.seed(seed = 10)),
  Variable1 = sample(1:200,1440, replace = TRUE, set.seed(seed = 187)),
  Variable2 = sample(300:800,1440, replace = TRUE, set.seed(seed = 333))
)
Measurings_xts <- xts(Measurings[,-1], Measurings$Time)
HourEnds <- endpoints(Measurings_xts, "hours")
Measurings_mean <- period.apply(Measurings_xts, HourEnds, mean)
```

I thought it would be easy to just change the function argument from `mean` to `max`, like this:

```
Measurings_max <- period.apply(Measurings_xts, HourEnds, max)
```

It delivers output, but only one column with the overall maximum values. I need the hourly maximums of each column. A simple solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mean` example works by column because there's a zoo method that calls `mean` on each column (this method is used because xts extends zoo).

The `max` example returns one number because there is no `max.xts` or `max.zoo` method, so it returns the maximum of the entire xts/zoo object.

A simple solution is to define a helper function:

```
colMax <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  apply(x, 2, max, na.rm = na.rm)
}
```

Then use that in your `period.apply` call:

```
epHours <- endpoints(Measurings_xts, "hours")
Measurings_max <- period.apply(Measurings_xts, epHours, colMax)
head(Measurings_max)
#                     Temp Variable1 Variable2
# 2018-05-18 00:50:00   29       194       787
# 2018-05-18 01:50:00   28       178       605
# 2018-05-18 02:50:00   26       188       756
# 2018-05-18 03:50:00   34       152       444
# 2018-05-18 04:50:00   33       145       724
# 2018-05-18 05:50:00   35       187       621
```

Comment: I did this `apply(ts, 2, function(x) period.apply(x, ep, FUN = sum))` and it takes ~20s and the result is a matrix but `period.apply(ts_df, ep, FUN = function(x) apply(x, 2, FUN = sum))` took less than 2s and the result is a xts object. I just wanted to share.

Comment: Since I haven't completely understood what the function does(it works well though), could you help me out again and explain how it works? For the same data I need to find the maximum Value for the period 18:00 - 6:00 the following day and assign the Value to the day before. I assume it needs just a slight modification of the formula you provided.

Comment: Hi @KonradBauer. Please ask a new question. You can link to this question for context, but a new question will be more clear to others and easier to address than in these comments.  I don't follow StackOverflow much these days, so please email me with a link to the question if you want me to try to answer.