# Using xts with timespans crossing calendar dates: How to use period.apply (xts) or POSIXct datetime arguments in these cases in R?

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, xts, posixct

I have a problem applying a function (min) to a specific repeating time-period. Basically my data looks like in that sample:

```
library(xts)
start <- as.POSIXct("2018-05-18 00:00")
tseq <- seq(from = start, length.out = 1440, by = "10 mins")
Measurings <- data.frame(
  Time = tseq,
  Temp = sample(10:37,1440, replace = TRUE, set.seed(seed = 10)))
)
Measurings_xts <- xts(Measurings[,-1], Measurings$Time)
```

with much appreciated help ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623745/how-to-use-apply-daily-period-apply-for-calculating-maximum-per-column-in-xts-ti)), I managed to find out that `min` and `max` functions (contrary to `mean`, which works right away in `period.apply`) must be defined by a helper function and can then be calculated for logical datetime arguments(hours, days, years...) by using this solution:

```
colMin <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE) {
  apply(x, 2, min, na.rm = na.rm)
}

epHours <- endpoints(Measurings_xts, "hours")
Measurings_min <- period.apply(Measurings_xts, epHours, colMin)
```

For meteorological analyses I need to calculate further minima for a less intuitive timespan, crossing the calendar day, that I fail to define in code:

I need to output the minimum nighttime temperature from e.g. `2018-05-18 19:00`  to `2018-05-19 7:00` in the morning for each night in my dataset.

I have tried to move the timespan by manipulating(moving) the time column up or down, to include the nighttime in one calendar day. Since this solution is error-prone and doesn´t work for my real data, where some observations are missing. How do I use the `POSIXct datetime` and/or `xts` functionalities to calculate minima in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by creating your own "end points" when you use `period.apply`

```
# Choose the appropriate time ranges
z <- Measurings_xts["T19:00/T07:00"]
# Creating your own "endpoints":
epNights <- which(diff.xts(index(z), units = "mins") > 10) - 1
```

Subtract one off each index because the jumps are recorded at the start of the next "night interval" in the output from `which()`.

Then add the last data point in the data set to your end points vector, and you can then use this in `period.apply`

```
epNights <- c(epNights, nrow(z))

Measurings_min <- period.apply(z, epNights, colMin)
Measurings_min
# [,1]
# 2018-05-18 07:00:00   10
# 2018-05-19 07:00:00   10
# 2018-05-20 07:00:00   10
# 2018-05-21 07:00:00   10
# 2018-05-22 07:00:00   10
# 2018-05-23 07:00:00   10
# 2018-05-24 07:00:00   11
# 2018-05-25 07:00:00   10
# 2018-05-26 07:00:00   10
# 2018-05-27 07:00:00   10
# 2018-05-27 23:50:00   12
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one approach that works by defining a new group for each night interval

```
# define the time interval, e.g. from 19:00 to 7:00
from <- 19
to <- 7
hours <- as.numeric(strftime(index(Measurings_xts), format="%H"))
y <- rle(as.numeric(findInterval(hours, c(to,from)) != 1))
y$values[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <-  cumsum(y$values[c(TRUE, FALSE)])
grp <- inverse.rle(y)
# grp is a grouping variable that is 0 for everything outside the 
# defined interval , 1 for the first night, 2 for the second...


s <- split(Measurings_xts, grp); s$`0` <- NULL
# min_value will contain the minimum value for each night interval 
min_value <- sapply(s, min)

# to see the date interval for each value
start <- sapply(s, function(x) as.character(index(x)[1]))
end <- sapply(s, function(x) as.character(index(x)[length(x)]))
data.frame(start, end, min_value)

#                start                 end   min_value
#1           2018-05-18 2018-05-18 06:50:00         10
#2  2018-05-18 19:00:00 2018-05-19 06:50:00         10
#3  2018-05-19 19:00:00 2018-05-20 06:50:00         10
#4  2018-05-20 19:00:00 2018-05-21 06:50:00         10
#5  2018-05-21 19:00:00 2018-05-22 06:50:00         10
#6  2018-05-22 19:00:00 2018-05-23 06:50:00         10
#7  2018-05-23 19:00:00 2018-05-24 06:50:00         11
#8  2018-05-24 19:00:00 2018-05-25 06:50:00         10
#9  2018-05-25 19:00:00 2018-05-26 06:50:00         10
#10 2018-05-26 19:00:00 2018-05-27 06:50:00         10
#11 2018-05-27 19:00:00 2018-05-27 23:50:00         12
```